# Move two tables with the same IDs in datas between DataBases

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have got two databases with the same structure, but different datas.
And... in both databases all datas have auto-incerement IDs in columns 'Tiles' and 'TilesData' and these IDs are related keys. I have to move rows from first one to another, but there is exception with id.

Is description of my problem clearly?
[image]

I tried this (but I'm a little afraid of reliability of this solution, there will be few millions of rows):

```
INSERT INTO DataBase_2.Tiles (X,Y,Zoom,Type,CacheTime)
    SELECT X, Y, Zoom, Type, CacheTime FROM DataBase_1.Tiles;
INSERT INTO DataBase_2.TilesData(Tile)
    SELECT Tile FROM DataBase_1.TilesData;
```

Could you help me or give me some tips? Is simply SQL enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the autoincrementing columns are declared as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (*without* AUTOINCREMENT), then new IDs will get the next value after the largest value already in the table.

Check if both tables have the same maximum ID value:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM DataBase_2.Tiles;
SELECT MAX(id) FROM DataBase_2.TilesData;
```

If they are equal, then corresponding rows will indeed get the same new ID. However, you should use ORDER BY to ensure that the rows are read/inserted in the same order:

```
INSERT INTO DataBase_2.Tiles    (...)
    SELECT ...  FROM DataBase_1.Tiles     ORDER BY id;
INSERT INTO DataBase_2.TilesData(Tile)
    SELECT Tile FROM DataBase_1.TilesData ORDER BY id;
```

---

If the `id` columns *are* declared with AUTOINCREMENT, then you have to check (and if needed, adjust) the next ID values in the [sqlite_sequence table](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#seqtab).

Comment: Yes, both tables have the same maximum ID value. I have run these two Inserts, first one was finishes successful, but second one showed me error:
[10:18:50] Error while executing SQL query on database 'DataBase_2': insert on table "TilesData" violates foreign key constraint "fki_TilesData_id_Tiles_id"

Are these triggers important or could I drop them (Inserts work then)?
http://i.imgur.com/t5P4W4E.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/jWMzvfT.jpg

Comment: The purpose of that trigger is to check that the IDs match, but it doesn't work when using the autoincrement function. You have to (temporarily) drop it.